# in C# try-finally how to catch the original exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch, try-finally

My simple example is:

```
    void FixedUnalterableMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception 1"); //line 12.
        }
        finally
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception 2"); //line 16.
        }
    }

    void Method1()
    {
        try
        {
            FixedUnalterableMethod(); //line 24.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var messageWithStackTrace = ex.ToString(); //line 28.
            Console.WriteLine(messageWithStackTrace);
        }
    }
```

The console output is:

```
System.Exception: Exception 2
    at Program.FixedUnalterableMethod() in ...\Program.cs:line 16
    at Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 24
```

The question is, how to be informed that the `Exception 1` has occured?
Is there a way how to include `Exception 1` in my StackTrace (in line 28.) ?

Of coure I can't modify the `FixedUnalterableMethod()` method!

Comment: No, you can't. Exception 1 was discarded when Exception 2 was thrown.

Comment: Why do you want to throw an exception in `finally`? It seems strange that you would have a method you always want to fail.

Comment: @John The `FixedUnalterableMethod` method is in external dll, and I can't change it. But I would like to know that the `Exception 1` has occurred.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, though pretty nasty!

It is a little known fact that CLR exceptions do not cause the execution of `finally` blocks until the exception has actually been caught. This is disguised somewhat because if an exception is not caught (and makes it out of `Main`) then the default behaviour of the CLR hosting code is to run `finally` blocks for you, giving the illusion that they always run.

However, there is a way to examine an exception *before* catching it, to decide if you want to catch it. Try this:

```
static bool StoreFirstException(Exception x, Action<Exception> store)
{
    if (x.Message == "Exception 1")
    {
        store(x);                
    }

    return true;
}

static void Method1()
{
    Exception firstException = null;

    try
    {
        FixedUnalterableMethod(); //line 24.
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (StoreFirstException(ex, x => firstException = x))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(firstException);               
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

The `catch... when` feature lets you write a boolean expression to examine the exception. Here I check the message (the only distinguishing fact you've given me) and if it's the first exception I pass it to the `store` action.

The caller uses this callback to stash the first exception.

Then it votes to catch, which only then causes the `finally` block to execute, which throws the second exception. The same `when` clause examines it but this time doesn't offer it to `store`. So then I have both exceptions in the `catch` block and I log them both. My console shows the two exceptions with the correct source line numbers.

Here's version that doesn't look at the message; it just assumes the first exception it see must be the interesting one. Also it's neater to use a nested function:

```
static void Method1()
{
    Exception firstException = null;

    bool StoreFirstException(Exception x)
    {
        if (firstException == null) firstException = x;
        return true;
    }

    try
    {
        FixedUnalterableMethod(); //line 24.
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (StoreFirstException(ex))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(firstException);               
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic! A lovely little nugget of almost-always-useless but fascinating information

Comment: Very interesting, always amazing to find language features like this. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If the "exception type" is literally the same you probably have little choice but the examine the `Message` property, which can be problematic to say the least.

Looking at that code again you will only ever see the 1 exception anyway, the one on line 16.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Daniel Earwicker the working solution is:

```
void FixedUnalterableMethod()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception 1"); //line 12.
    }
    finally
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception 2"); //line 16.
    }
}

void Method1()
{
    bool CatchException(Exception ex)
    {
        //Log...

        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    try
    {
        FixedUnalterableMethod(); //line 24.
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (CatchException(ex))
    {
        //do something with the lastest exception
    }
}
```

Comment: So traditionally at this point you would accept my answer! No need to post another copy of it. :)